LitElement with SASS
I am currently using Lit to learn more about custom web components and I am trying to use .scss files to render an style for my components; but I can't find a way to compile the scss files in a way the 'import {styles} from "[...]"' can understand.
import { html, LitElement} from "lit";
import { styles } from "./component-styles/_greenbutton.js";

export class greenButton extends LitElement {
    static styles = [styles];

    render() {
        return html`
        <button>I am green</button>
        `
    };
}

In this current version, i can import the '.js' file, but it doesn't support any different extensions files, including '.css', '.scss'.
I normally use 'gulp.js' and 'gulp-sass' for compiling the sass files into an css output
const {src, dest, watch, series} = require('gulp');
const sass = require('gulp-sass')(require('sass'));

function construtor(){
    return src('styles/**/*.scss')
        .pipe(sass())
        .pipe(dest('css'))

}

function observador(){
    watch(['styles/**/*.scss'], construtor)
}

exports.default = series(construtor, observador)

Just like in this 'gulpfile.js', I can compile all my scss files into a single output.
But, unfortunelly the 'import from' doesn't support file different of '.js' ones...
Note that I am not using typescript and i would like to stay using gulp if posssible. I also render my Lit components with Vite.
Any help means a lot. Thanks.
